# What is the slack API workspace rate limit for chat.postMessage

Tags: slack, slack-api, rate-limiting

I am trying to use postMessage for posting message in slack. I want to know the Rate Limit for [chat.postMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#rate-limiting) for a workspace.

Found this in the document:

> chat.postMessage has special rate limiting conditions. It will generally allow an app to post 1 message per second to a specific channel. There are limits governing your app's relationship with the entire workspace above that, limiting posting to several hundred messages per minute. Generous burst behavior is also granted.

But what I could not understand is -

- What is the *several hundred messages*?
- After how many messages will the app be blocked?

Can anyone please guide me through this? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There are several tier for rating limits [Doc](https://api.slack.com/docs/rate-limits). Tier 4, for example, goes up to 100+ per minute. But basically, it's 1 message per second per channel. Sometimes when you end up sending too much messages at once, going above 1 message per second or N messages per minute, all the messages COULD be sent, since there's a "burst behavior" granted. But depending on the quantity, it's not guaranteed.